# Recursively scanning for a child propery or state via script in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to write a utility function to get the (first) `title` propery of the current component (of the route).

I can get the tile property of the route:

```
function getPageTitleByRoutes(routes) {
  for (let i = routes.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
    if (routes[i].hasOwnProperty('title')) {
      return routes[i].title;
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

But now I want move the title prop to my components:

```
function getPageTitle(props) {
  // ?? Iterate recurively ?? Context ok on render ??
  React.Children.forEach(props.children, (child, i) => {
    console.log(child + ' at index: ' + i);
    // If it has title
    // ??
    // ??
    if(title) return title;
    return getPageTitle(child.props);
  });

  return null;
}
```

I have a component setup like this under react router:

```
<Router>
  <Route path="/" title="App Title" component={App}>
    <Route path="page1" title="Comp A" component={Comp1} />
    <Route path="page2" title="Comp B" component={Comp2} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/login" title="Login Comp" component={Login} />
</Router>


var NavBar = React.createClass({
  render() {
    const someTitle = getPageTitleByRoutes(this.props.routes);
    // Line above works but now want to get 'title' (defaultProps)
    // from "active/routed" component:
    const someTitle = getPageTitle(this.props);
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{someTitle}</h2>
        <ul>
          <a onClick={() => history.push('page1') }>Page 1</a>
          <a onClick={() => history.push('page2') }>Page 2</a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

Then I create my app like this:

```
var App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar />
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

Maybe there is another approach? I also have react-redux connected...

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing any props nor any children to your `<NavBar />` component.  This is why `this.props.routes` and `this.props.children` are empty.

Try giving `<NavBar />` a route prop and some children.  You decide what to add there.

For example:

`<NavBar routes={[{title: 'First Title'}, {title: 'Second Title'}]} />`

Or passing along your `<App />`'s children like it looked like you may have intended but like so:

`<NavBar>
     {this.props.children}
</NavBar>`

Comment: Interesting, but it feels weird to gave <NavBar this.props.cildren> and then render them after on the next line. Conceptually the NavBar is not the owner of <Apps/>'s children.

Comment: You don't need to put your App's children within your NavBar of course.  NavBar definitely needs props passed to it, like `routes={...}`, otherwise you won't be able to act on them as `this.props.routes` within your NavBar's render.